# Emission Material adding Noise to Otherwise Clean Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am facing issue with emission material. 
As soon I add an emission material to a render it becomes noisy. Even if the emission material is added to a small portion of the object the entire object becomes noisy in rendering.

Please see the images below for your reference 
[image: render with and without emission]

I have added a curve to increase the brightness - this makes the noise more evident
[image: render brightened with curve]

Could anyone suggest why it's happening and if there is any solution to address such emission noise issue?

I posted the blender file if anyone wants it for inspection.

[image]

Comment: Here is the link of the blend file in case anyone wants to inspect it:
https://mega.nz/#!wJtwnJJQ

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for uploading .blend files and add the link you are provided into your question as an edit to your your post. The link you have provided does not have the correct permissions enabled it appears.

Comment: Timaroberts: Thanks for the .blend file host.
Here is the link for my file http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2970/

Comment: Increase the number of samples.

Comment: Have you tried Branched Path Tracing?